# QT - How to synchronize data between two widgets?

Tags: qt, widget, synchronize

I have a QT program with a custom widget that I'm implementing. This widget is an Hexeditor, and it's already functional.
But now I want to put on the window another instance of the same Hexeditor, and I want to synchronize the data between them, so if I change a byte in one Hexeditor, the same byte is automatically changed on the other Hexeditor.

What is the best solution for this problem? What are my options? Sometimes the files can be very big, so I'm trying to find the best solution.

This is a general question, and probably is valid for other text widgets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the very good MVC architecture widgets in Qt.

As a hexeditor is generally laid out as a table, I would use `QAbstractTableModel` to actually store the hex data, and then `QTableView` to display the data.  You can then have an arbitrary mount of hex editors connected to the same model and all will be synchronised automatically.  You will also have to modify a `QStyledItemDelegate` to provide hex-only editing in the view, but that's really straightforward.